# Please mark "Modal Cadence Options" as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, flagging

02fentym had posted a question titled [Modal Cadence Options](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/58128/modal-cadence-options).  This question is seemingly a duplicate of [Cadences for Modes](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42552/cadences-for-modes), which is another question asked by the exact same user.  The problem here, is that I flagged it to close and it was accepted, but the question was not closed which is strange.  I'm wondering if this is due to a bug or something.

[image]

So I'm doubling down on my closure flag here.

Can we close this question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have *flagged* the question as a duplicate, but you have not *voted* to close the question because you don't have the reputation to do that yet. When you flag a question as a duplicate, it shows up in the review queues of users who can vote to close so that they may decide what to do with the question.

That the question was not closed the first time indicates that the community did not agree with you. That your flag was marked helpful indicates that the flag was, er, *helpful*. Either *someone* agreed with you, or a moderator felt that while the question does not warrant a unilateral closure, it is a bit of a border case and it was helpful to bring attention to it with a flag.

In a comment under an answer to your earlier question on the same topic, [Do we accept duplicates of questions that are posted by the same user?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3289/39614), @DoktorMayhem writes: "it isn't closed because despite the titles, they are not duplicates." I think that the point here is that one question asks whether the **I** chord of a mode should be preceded by any particular chord, while the other question asks for each possibility for all of the modes.

This does seem like a case where two questions that aren't duplicates of each other may be answerable with the same answers. An answer to the more detailed question might also be an answer to the broader question, but an answer to the broader question may not be an answer to the more detailed one. Yet the fact that the answers to two questions could overlap does not necessarily make the questions duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I wasn't aware closure votes and flags were completely different from each other.